# Symfony using multiple entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I wrote a Symfony 5.0 application for a company, with Doctrine.
The application needs to manage two identical databases that cannot be collapsed in a single one.
As suggested in the official documentation i edited:
doctrine.yaml

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: default
        connections:
            default:
                url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL_FAU)%'
                driver: 'pdo_mysql'
                server_version: '8.0'
            cef:
                url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL_CEF)%'
                driver: 'pdo_mysql'
                server_version: '8.0'

    orm:
        default_entity_manager: default
        entity_managers:
            default:
                connection: default
                mappings:
                    App:
                        is_bundle: false
                        type: annotation
                        dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                        prefix: 'App\Entity'
                        alias: Fau
            cef:
                connection: cef
                mappings:
                    Cef:
                        is_bundle: false
                        type: annotation
                        dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                        prefix: 'App\Entity'
                        alias: Cef
```

Then edited all my Controller's functions setting the entity manager and the repository this way:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager($this->security->getUser()->getEnte());

$gruppiRepository = $em->getRepository(Gruppi::class, $this->security->getUser()->getEnte());
```

The second argument of getRepository and getManager, returns correctly the name of secondary entity manager connection ("cef").
But i always get results from "default".

This is the dd($em) of the entity Manager:

```
GruppiController.php on line 95:
Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager {#714 ▼
  -config: Doctrine\ORM\Configuration {#596 ▶}
  -conn: Doctrine\DBAL\Connection {#712 ▼
    #_conn: null
    #_config: Doctrine\DBAL\Configuration {#703 ▶}
    #_eventManager: Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\ContainerAwareEventManager {#707 ▶}
    #_expr: Doctrine\DBAL\Query\Expression\ExpressionBuilder {#713 ▶}
    -isConnected: false
    -autoCommit: true
    -transactionNestingLevel: 0
    -transactionIsolationLevel: null
    -nestTransactionsWithSavepoints: false
    -params: array:11 [▼
      "url" => "mysql://root:1234@127.0.0.1:3306/fgc_cef"
      "driver" => "pdo_mysql"
      "host" => "127.0.0.1"
      "port" => "3306"
      "user" => "root"
      "password" => "1234"
      "driverOptions" => []
      "serverVersion" => "8.0"
      "defaultTableOptions" => array:1 [▶]
      "dbname" => "fgc_cef"
      "charset" => "utf8mb4"
    ]
    -platform: null
    #_schemaManager: null
    #_driver: Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver {#709}
    -isRollbackOnly: false
    #defaultFetchMode: 2
  }
  -metadataFactory: Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory {#715 ▶}
  -unitOfWork: Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork {#716 ▶}
  -eventManager: Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\ContainerAwareEventManager {#707 ▶}
  -proxyFactory: Doctrine\ORM\Proxy\ProxyFactory {#722 ▶}
  -repositoryFactory: Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Repository\ContainerRepositoryFactory {#590 ▶}
  -expressionBuilder: null
  -closed: false
  -filterCollection: null
  -cache: null
}
```

So, the database connection is correct... but i still get results from "default".
Same things for $gruppiRepository.

I don't want to edit my Entity folder structure putting identical Entity Files in two separate directory.

What shall i do?

Best regards,

G.V.

[EDIT]
I solved this way:
in each repository create a new function

```
public function setEntityManager(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager): self
    {
        $this->_em = $entityManager;

        return $this;
    }
```

then change every repository call with (for example if you want to perform a findAll():

```
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager($this->security->getUser()->getEnte());
        $gruppi = $em->getRepository(Gruppi::class)->setEntityManager($em)->findAll();
```

Comment: Are your repositories extending from ServiceEntityRepository?  If so, one of the unfortunate implementation details is that they will always use the first entity manager which supports the entity.  Changing them to extend EntityRepository should help.

Comment: You can find some about this issue and workarounds here - https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs/issues/9878

Comment: @EugeneRuban I looked at your link and found it quite confusing.  Never did see an actual resolution.  Don't know if the op will respond but if they are using the ServiceEntityRepository then the solution is to not use it.  Like we did back in ancient times.

Comment: @Cerad, ok, thanks, but now i got:

Argument 1 passed to App\Repository\GruppiRepository::__construct() must implement interface Doctrine\Persistence\ManagerRegistry, instance of Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager given, called in C:\Users\Giacomo\Documents\GitHub\fgcweb\vendor\doctrine\doctrine-bundle\Repository\ContainerRepositoryFactory.php on line 86

while my constructor is:
`
    public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $registry)
    {
        parent::__construct($registry, Gruppi::class);
    }
`

Comment: No constructor needed when extending EntityRepository.  Just be sure to add your Entity repository directory to the exclude list in services.yaml.